# Radio buttons to popup more information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out a way that the course selections could be linked to our course descriptions and I am unsure where I could start to do something like that  how can i have some sort of pop-up that i could incorporate more information on each of the radio buttons?

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="8" border="1">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="20%" valign="top">
            <label for="Lit">Literature:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="Lit" type="radio" value="Eng150" required>English 150
            <br>
            <input name="Lit" type="radio" value="Lit150" required>Literature 150
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for="Phl">Philopsphy:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="Phl" type="radio" value="Phl151" required>Philosophy 151
            <br>
            <input name="Phl" type="radio" value="Phl152" required>Philosophy 152
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for "rel"="">Religion:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="Rel" type="radio" value="Rel150" required>Religion 150
            <br>
            <input name="Rel" type="radio" value="Rel151" required>Religion 151
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width="23%" valign="top">
            <label for "hist"="">History:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="Hist" type="radio" value="Hist151" required>History 152
            <br>
            <input name="Hist" type="radio" value="Hist155">History 155
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for "artlang"="">Fine Arts or Language:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="ArtLang" type="radio" value="Art150" required>Art 150
            <br>
            <input name="ArtLang" type="radio" value="Mus150" required>Music 150
            <br>
            <input name="ArtLang" type="radio" id="langSelect" value="Lang" required>Foreign Language (use selection below)
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width="34%" valign="top">
            <label for="NatSci">Natural Science:</label>
            <br>
            <input name="NatSci" type="radio" value="Bio157" required>Biology 157
            <br>
            <input name="NatSci" type="radio" value="Bio158" required>Biology 158
            <br>
            <br>
            <label for "socsci1"="">Social Sciences (choose one from each pair):</label>
            <br>
            <input name="SocSci" type="radio" value="Econ150" required>Econimics 150
            <br>
            <input name="SocSci" type="radio" value="Pol151" required>Political Science 151
            <br>
            <hr width="75%" align="left">
            <input name="SocSci2" type="radio" value="Psy155" required>Psychology 155
            <br>
            <input name="SocSci2" type="radio" value="Soc150" required>Sociology 150
            <br>
        </td>
        <td width="23%" valign="top"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? If its about the popup investigate JavaScript and jquery

Comment: Questions usually have a question mark (`?`). Where is yours?

Comment: trying to find a way to incorporate more information into each radio button selection when this was in paper form there was an attached paper with the description of each course

Comment: @burntehsky - Edit your question to incorporate the, um, question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood the question properly, but I would just add normal hyperlinks that lead to the description of each course. JavaScript could convert the hyperlinks to open AJAX modals or accordions that contain the description of the course which was clicked on.

If you could elaborate on what exactly *"the course selections could be linked somehow to our course descriptions somehow"* means, we could aid in choosing a proper technique for the implementation. Are there any known requirements on the implementation (either by UI or by technology)?

Comment: I was thinking, if possible, something like a lightbox it would come up within the page that would display the course information needed.

Comment: Yes, you could use AJAX to read the description contents from behind the hyperlink of each radio button and set it to open as a lightbox modal on top of the page.

Comment: Ok, is there any kind of example you could possibly point me to so i can get a better idea what this would look like? I get what you mean just not sure on how to accomplish it.